# ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter only showing first value

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

Trying to fill in a listview from a simplecursoradaptor, all it will add to the view is the first entry from the cursor, although the cursor does have all the data....

**EDIT:** Just for testing, I tried changing it to an ArrayAdapter filled with static data, and got the same results.

**MORE EDIT:** Also, I tried using a ListFragment, and android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and still, the same results.

the code for it is

**AllWeeksFragment**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import us.emanon.timecard.db.HoursDataSource;

public class AllWeeksFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private HoursDataSource dataSource = HoursDataSource.getInstance(getActivity());
    private Cursor mCursor;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    public static AllWeeksFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AllWeeksFragment fragment = new AllWeeksFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public AllWeeksFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        dataSource.open();
        mCursor = dataSource.getAllWeeks();
        dataSource.displayCursor(mCursor);
    }

    ListView mListView;

    private void displayList() {

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "count=" + mCursor.getCount());
        String[] from = new String[] {
                "_id",
                "weekHours"
        };

        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.allWeek,
                R.id.allHours
        };

        MyCursorAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.row_layout,
                mCursor,
                from,
                to,
                0
        );

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_weeks, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.all_list);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(id);
                }
            }
        });
        displayList();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dataSource.close();
    }

    /**
    * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
    * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
    * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
    * activity.
    * <p>
    * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
    * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
    * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
    */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Long id);
    }

    //extend the SimpleCursorAdapter to create a custom class where we
    //can override the getView to change the row colors
    private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "position="+position);
            //get reference to the row
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row background
            if(position % 2 == 0){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 233, 233));
            }
            else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

and

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/allWeekRow">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/allWeek"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/allHours"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and

**HoursDataSource**

```
public void displayCursor(Cursor c) {
    int i=1;
    String[] cols = c.getColumnNames();
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "count="+c.getCount());
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        for(String col : cols) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), i + " " + col + "=" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(col)));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
/*
 * TODO: attach YearTable as db1;
 * TODO: attach HOURS as db2;
 * TODO: select wkStart, wkEnd, payWeek as _id, (SUM(hMinutes) - SUM(lunch))/60.0 as weekHours from HOURS b inner join YearTable a on a.wkNum = b.payWeek group by b.payWeek order by b.payWeek ASC
 */
public Cursor getAllWeeks() {
    Cursor c = null;
    String query = "select payWeek as _id, (SUM(hMinutes) - SUM(lunch))/60.0 as weekHours from hours group by payWeek order by payWeek ASC";
    try {
        c = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.toString());
    }
    return c;
}
```

**fragment_all_weeks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listFrame">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/all_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Week"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Hours"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/all_list"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/all_header"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/all_header" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

from MainActivity: (navigation drawer layout)

```
    case 3:
        fragment = AllWeeksFragment.newInstance(null, null);
        tag = "all";
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack("home")
                .commit();
        break;
```

the logcat output with some debugging says everything is there....

```
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ count=4
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 1 _id=34
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 1 weekHours=11.75
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 2 _id=35
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 2 weekHours=7
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 3 _id=36
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 3 weekHours=8.75
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 4 _id=37
09-29 14:34:46.345  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/HoursDataSource﹕ 4 weekHours=55.25
09-29 14:34:46.355  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/AllWeeksFragment﹕ count=4
09-29 14:34:46.365  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/MyCursorAdapter﹕ position=0
09-29 14:34:46.375  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/MyCursorAdapter﹕ position=0
09-29 14:34:46.375  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/MyCursorAdapter﹕ position=0
09-29 14:34:46.375  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/MyCursorAdapter﹕ position=0
09-29 14:34:46.375  24370-24370/us.emanon.timecard D/MyCursorAdapter﹕ position=0
```

[image]

I've tried moving things around, putting them in different places (onCreate, onCreateView, etc), changing local variables to fields, etc. and everything gives the same result.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I frankly just can't find it.

Comment: Post the fragment layout. Where do you add this fragment?

Comment: Posted.  I also tried removing the _id from being displayed in case that was fouling something up. no luck.

Comment: From what you posted there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. Check the layout where you place the fragment and see if you're not hiding it or limiting its size somehow.

Comment: That was the problem. I forgot I had used a ScrollView wrapping a framelayout for my container.  A much smaller problem to work around in the other fragments.  I compleatly forgot about checking there.  Thanks!